# 1st Gen MacBook Air Charger: Will it work with Late 2010 MBA?

Tags: macbook-pro, charging, magsafe

The original MacBook Air's charger looks a little different than the L-connector MagSafe 1 that the later gen Macbook Air's have.  Here's the first gen:

[image: Original MBA charger]

It looks like the actual plug interface is the same, just the external housing is different.  The wattage is also 45w.

Are they interchangeable?

My MBA: Late 2010 13 inch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will still work. The situation you want to avoid is using the incorrect wattage.

Comment: I thought increased chargers were intelligent enough to step down their wattage output.

Comment: @PatrickMcMahon It's more about using the lower wattages on the higher-powered machine. I'd rephrase and say that it is always recommended that you use the adapter that was rated for your model :)

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  Unfortunately, some folks have to use what they have available at the time.  Again, I've understood higher rated ones step down, and the lesser wattage chargers work, yet they may take longer as they aren't pushing as much juice.  I think iPads trying to charge using the small iPhone plugs are the only instance where they won't charge at all.

Comment: Confirmed.  I bought it and despite the different shape it charges the same.